# Getting linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) error

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

Getting error when running the app in iPad.I am using ios6 and xcode 4.5

[image: Error when running in iPad]

In simulator its working fine.

Please help me...

Comment: Did you try a clean build on both targets, as well as rm -fr ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData? A typical cause is that a library or framework you're using already includes a library you're explicitly using. . . that it works on simulator but not device is puzzling though.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
- Clean and build
- Delete the derived data folder
- Deleting the app from your iPad and building again.
- Recompile any libraries you are using for the project